# Collapse by values

Tags: aggregate, stata, frequency

I have a dataset that looks like this (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ... have possible values of 1,2,3,4,5,6).

`var1` (3,3,4,1,2,4,5,6...) `var2` (4,5,2,2,3,1,6,6...) `var3` (1,2,2,4,2,3,6,5...)

And I'd like to collapse the count of the values of `var1 var2 var3`... by values (1,2,3,4,5,6) and create a dataset like this:

`value`(1,2,3,4,5,6)

`var1_count`(1,1,2,2,1,1)

`var2_count`(1,2,1,1,1,2)

`var3_count`(1,3,1,1,1,1)

I tried the command `collapse(count)`, but I don't have a grouping variable. Is there a way to aggregate variables by their values?

Comment: Can you format your post? You can use apostrophe to separate `your values` or `your codes`. You can leave two linebreak to separate your paragraphes.

Comment: @M.Pflaumbaum It is better to add these details in directly in your question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Please read advice on MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Your data can be read in as follows.

```
clear 

mat var1 = (3,3,4,1,2,4,5,6) 
mat var2 = (4,5,2,2,3,1,6,6) 
mat var3 = (1,2,2,4,2,3,6,5) 

set obs 8 
forval j = 1/3 { 
    gen var`j' = var`j'[1, _n] 
}

list, sep(0) 

     +--------------------+
     | var1   var2   var3 |
     |--------------------|
  1. |    3      4      1 |
  2. |    3      5      2 |
  3. |    4      2      2 |
  4. |    1      2      4 |
  5. |    2      3      2 |
  6. |    4      1      3 |
  7. |    5      6      6 |
  8. |    6      6      5 |
     +--------------------+
```

One way to get that tabulation is to install `tabm` using

```
ssc install tab_chi 
help tabm 
tabm var? 

           |                              values
  variable |         1          2          3          4          5          6 |     Total
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
      var1 |         1          1          2          2          1          1 |         8 
      var2 |         1          2          1          1          1          2 |         8 
      var3 |         1          3          1          1          1          1 |         8 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         3          6          4          4          3          4 |        24
```

`tabm` also offers a `replace` option to save the tabulation as a new dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, I tried to save the tabulation by `tabm var*, replace` and I got a dataset of two variables: `_stack` and `_values`.  <br/>
_stack(var1,var2,var3...)  <br/>
_values(3,3,4,1,2,4,5,6,4,5,2,2,3,1,6,6,1,2,2,4,2,3,6,5)  <br/>
How do I generate the counts of 1,2,3,4,5,6 as frequency variables?

Comment: `contract _values _stack` followed by `reshape wide _freq, i(_stack) j(_values)` may be what you are asking for.